# Retained size of Javascript Object full of Booleans

Tags: javascript, memory-management, google-chrome-devtools

I am new to using Chrome's profiler.  So this might be a misinterpretation of the results I'm getting.

If I open Chromes profiler and take a heap snapshot of the following webpage I notice that obj3, has more than ten times the retained size of obj1 and obj2.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        // return an object with s keys, with values alternating true and false
        var makeData = function (s) {
            var o = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < s; i++) {
                o['data' + i] = !!(i % 2);
            }
            return o;
        }

        window.obj1 = makeData(14);
        window.obj2 = makeData(15);

        window.obj3 = makeData(16);
        window.obj4 = makeData(17);
        window.obj5 = makeData(18);


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It appears that an Object with less than 15 fields containing boolean values always has a retained size of 80, but more 16 fields has a retained size of 828, 17 has 848, 18 has 868, ect...
I'm curious whats happening here?

If it matters, I'm using Chome Version 27.0.1453.110 on a macbook running 10.6.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object in JavaScript is a map.  The simplest way to store this structure under the hood is a list of key/value pairs - to search/update, you iterate through all of them looking for a match.  The computational cost of a lookup is obviously proportional to the number of key/value pairs you have (`O(n)`), but when you have a small number of key/value pairs, this is OK.

However, for a larger number of keys, it is more efficient to use a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).  Lookup in a hash table is constant-time (`O(1)`), but that constant time is non-trivial.

My guess is that the V8 JavaScript engine in Chrome swaps between these two setups depending on which it thinks will be more efficient, and you have simply located the threshold for this switch.